# Incluir tag na primeira palavra de uma string

Tags: php, regex

Não tenho muito conhecimento de regex, então peguei esta regra pronta.

```
$break_title = preg_replace('/(?<=\>)\b\w*\b|^\w*\b/', '<span>$0</span>', $title);
return $break_title;
```

O problema é que ela não reconhece o cedilha, de forma que a string abaixo:

```
construções importantes
```

Fica assim:

```
<span>constru</span>ções importantes
```

Comment: Pode explicar qual é o padrão que tem? quais são os valores que `$title` pode ter? Os carateres especiais e particulares de cada lingua não se enquadram de facto na regex que tem.

Comment: @Sergio Os valores de title serão dinâmicos. Então tenho que prever o uso de letras acentuadas e com cedilha.

Comment: Já testou `\p{L}`?

Comment: @Sergio Qual parte devo substituir?

Comment: marcelo, na verdade talvez isto baste: http://ideone.com/ABs2z5 é isto que procura?

Comment: @Sergio funcionou! E ficou bem mais simples hein. Posta como resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sugiro que procure esse espaço em branco e "corte" a frase por aí. Nesse caso basta esta regex:

```
/([^\s]+)\s/
```

#### Exemplo: http://ideone.com/ABs2z5

```
$title = 'construções importantes';
echo preg_replace('/([^\s]+)\s/', '<span>$0</span>', $title);
```

O que esta regex faz é capturar - usando `()` todo o conteudo que não fôr um espaço branco. Usando o `^` dentro de `[]` significa negação, e `\s` para espaço branco. O `+` indica 1 ou mais vezes. Usando `\s` no fim é uma ideia que funciona caso nunca tenha um title a acabar com espaço branco.

**Talvez seja melhor** fazer `/^([^\s]+)\s/` que neste caso diz que a string começa sem um espaço no inicio.

#### Exemplo: http://ideone.com/ntKNNv